# Is it possible for a contract to update the amount of tokens owned by an address, according to a parameter called with Oraclize?

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to figure out if a contract can change the amount of tokens owned by an address according to certain parameters. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Better example: Let's say Ethereum price is $200. I send 1 ETH to the contract and I receive 200 tokens. Price goes down to 190, the contract calls an api, finds the new price, then update my balance to 190 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If the contract was programmed to do so it will be able to. But a contract cannot execute itself on its own, it has to be someone else calling a function in the contract.

In the case of an oracle often the results are not returned immediately but in another transaction some blocks later. That transaction will execute the contract callback.

Contracts usually are protected so this callback function can only be called by the oracle. And oracles usually do not have the incentives to pay for multiple calls.